# How to stop automatically Billing in Heroku website?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, web-hosting, billing

I am kind of scared of filling billing information on the Heroku website because of the **automatic billing** option in case I forget to remove an account.

Help me with your experience.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku, charged me two to three times because I had apps.
I choose to leave, and it will recharge me without refund although there were 14 days passed. When i saw the charge there were 14 days passed and now i cannot leave the app if i dont pay one more time

Answer (score 0):

If you're still on free tier, it will not charge you. When I upgraded to hobby, I was only charged for how often the service was used (often less than $7). They were very honest - I have had no problems with Heroku. If you elaborate on your concerns, maybe I can provide a more tailored response.

You can stop charging at any time. If you're looking for specific information on how to remove your card/billing information, thus reducing down to the free tier you can change your dyno type in "Resources" on the Heroku web app.

Comment: Ma'am, I have Github student pack which gives me 2 years free of service. But it says to fill billing information. I don't want Heroku to charge without asking me.

Comment: It will not charge you for two years - the credit card authorization is probably to ensure that people don't exploit the service by creating multiple accounts.